# Beginner- align equations to the left

Tags: equations, align

I am total beginner, and I read all questions and response on this site, but still can not figure it out. I tried align* and flalign, but always is some error. Hope you can help.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

.........



\textbf{2.}Use the properties of logarithms:  
$$\log_2(x^4\sqrt{\frac{x}{z^3}})$$ $$\ln(\frac{7x^3\sqrt{x+1}}{5})$$
$$\log_8(x-1)=\log_8(x-2)-\log_8(x+2)$$
$$5\ln(x-2)-\ln(x+2)-3\ln(x)$$
```

Comment: Do you want all equations to begin at the left margin?

Comment: yes, left margin

Comment: please read a proper introduction to LaTeX. You will have more worries later if you continue the way you are going now.

Comment: Sure. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass[10pt,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in]{geometry}

\begin{document}
Something
\[\log_2\left(x^4\sqrt{\frac{x}{z^3}}\right)\]
\[\ln\left(\frac{7x^3\sqrt{x+1}}{5}\right)\]
\[\log_8(x-1)=\log_8(x-2)-\log_8(x+2)\]
\[5\ln(x-2)-\ln(x+2)-3\ln(x)\]
\end{document}

% Option `fleqn' align all display-style equations
% to the left margin, but you have to use LaTeX
% command \[ \] instead of plain TeX command $$ $$
```

[image]

or this?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
Something

\begin{align*}
    &\log_2\left(x^4\sqrt{\frac{x}{z^3}}\right)\\
    &\ln\left(\frac{7x^3\sqrt{x+1}}{5}\right)\\
    &\log_8(x-1)=\log_8(x-2)-\log_8(x+2)\\
    &5\ln(x-2)-\ln(x+2)-3\ln(x)
\end{align*}
\end{document}

% The `align' environment (provided by `amsmath')
% can align all lines in the equation but still 
% make the equation centered. You have to add a &
% to make the lines left-aligned. Read more in
% LaTeX introductory documents.
%
% `align*' is `align' but the lines are not numbered
```

[image]